# Changing the properties of existing PDF files - iText Java library

Tags: pdf, itext, java

I need to change the properties of existing PDF file like ( set author name , set subject etc .. ) i can create a new pdf file with iText java library and thereby i can set the properties. But i need to change the existing properties of the document (.pdf) . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `manipulatePdf()` method in [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=216). If you're talking about XMP, take a look at the method with the same name in [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=217).

If you're saying: but these examples create a new file, reconsider: even MS Word doesn't manipulate an existing file directly. Instead, it creates a temporary file and then replaces the original file with the temporary one.